# how do i add meta data to the Laravel Route::resource() method?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-10

I want to be able to add data to the Route::resource(), similar to

```
['names' => ['index' => 'home']]
```

but with `descriptions` instead of `names`.

I have managed to do this on a single route with these in the RouteServiceProvider:

```
    \Illuminate\Routing\Route::macro('addDescription', function ($description) {
        $this->action['meta']['description'] = $description;

        return $this;
    });

    \Illuminate\Routing\Route::macro('getDescription', function () {
        return $this->getAction('meta.description');
    });
```

and it works fine. The Route::resource() returns a `PendingResourceRegistration` class so I tried `PendingResourceRegistration::macro(...)` but it didn't work.